# Radwindow closes when Radgrid inside is sorted

Tags: radgrid, radwindow

I have a `RadWindow` containing a `RadGrid`. When a user clicks on a grid column to sort, it closes the `RadWindow`.

Is there an easy way to prevent the window from closing until they explicitly close it?

Thanks!

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="CashExposure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CashAdmin.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="formCashExposure" runat="server">
        <telerik:radskinmanager id="cashSkinMgr" runat="server" showchooser="False" skin="WebBlue" />
        <telerik:radscriptmanager id="CashRadScriptManager" runat="server" enablepagemethods="True" />
        <div id="divMain">
            <telerik:radtabstrip id="cashTabs" runat="server" text="Exposure Report" multipageid="cashMultiPage" selectedindex="0"
                ontabclick="tabStrip_onTabClick" reordertabsonselect="False" cssclass="radTabStrip"> 
                <Tabs>
                    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Exposure Detail Report" CssClass="radTab"></telerik:RadTab>
                    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Admin" CssClass="radTab"></telerik:RadTab>
                </Tabs>
            </telerik:radtabstrip>
            <telerik:radmultipage id="cashMultiPage" runat="server" selectedindex="0">
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="exposureReportTab" runat="server">
                    <uc1:ExposureReport runat="server" id="ExposureReport" />
                </telerik:RadPageView>
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="cashAdminTab" runat="server">
                    <uc1:CashAdmin runat="server" id="CashAdmin" />
                </telerik:RadPageView>
            </telerik:radmultipage>

            <telerik:radwindow id="DetailPopup" runat="server" width="800px" height="500px" modal="True">
            <ContentTemplate>
             <telerik:radgrid
                allowfilteringbycolumn="True"
                allowpaging="True"
                pagesize="40"
                allowsorting="True"
                autogeneratecolumns="False"
                autopostbackonfilter="False"
                enablepostbackonrowclick="False"

                onneeddatasource="gridDetailPopup_NeedDataSource"
                onitemdatabound="gridDetailPopup_ItemDataBound"
                onupdatecommand="gridDetailPopup_UpdateCommand"
                id="gridDetail"
                runat="server"
                width="780px">
                <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="False" />
                <GroupingSettings
                    CaseSensitive="False" />
                <ClientSettings
                    AllowKeyboardNavigation="False"
                    EnableRowHoverStyle="True"
                    EnablePostBackOnRowClick="False">
                    <KeyboardNavigationSettings
                        EnableKeyboardShortcuts="False" />
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" CellSelectionMode="SingleCell"></Selecting>
                </ClientSettings>
                <MasterTableView
                    TableLayout="Fixed" Height="14px" border-left-width="0px" Font-Names="Calibri" font-Size="9">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Location Account" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="LocationAccount" UniqueName="LocationAccount" >
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding"  Width="95px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="CCY" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Currency" UniqueName="Currency"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" Width="30px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Amount" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Amount" UniqueName="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:C0}"> <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Pay/Rec Type" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TransactionType" UniqueName="TransactionType"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" Width="130px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Settle Date" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.DateTime" 
                            DataField="SettleDate" UniqueName="SettleDate" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="55px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Transaction ID" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TransactionID" UniqueName="TransactionID"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" Width="90px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Geneva Trans ID" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="GenevaTransactionID" UniqueName="GenevaTransactionID"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" Width="90px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:radgrid>                

            </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:radwindow>
        </div>
<div>
    <div id="divExposureReport">
        <div id="divControls">
            <asp:Label ID="lbValueDate" runat="server" Text="Value Date" />
            <telerik:raddatepicker id="dpValueDate" runat="server" culture="en-US" autopostback="True" 
                onselecteddatechanged="dpValueDate_ChangedEvent" />
            <telerik:radbutton id="btRefresh" runat="server" text="Refresh" onclick="btRefreshExposureReport_Click"></telerik:radbutton>
            <telerik:radbutton id="ExportToExcel" runat="server" text="Export Excel" onclick="btExportToExcel_Click"></telerik:radbutton>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="exposureReportGrid">
            <telerik:radgrid
                allowfilteringbycolumn="True"
                allowpaging="True"
                PageSize="24"
                allowsorting="True"
                autogeneratecolumns="False"
                autopostbackonfilter="False"
                enablepostbackonrowclick="False"
                onneeddatasource="gridExposureReport_NeedDataSource"
                onitemdatabound="gridExposureReport_ItemDataBound"
                onupdatecommand="gridExposureReport_UpdateCommand"
                id="gridExposureReport"
                runat="server"
                width="2400px">
                <SortingSettings EnableSkinSortStyles="False" />
                <GroupingSettings
                    CaseSensitive="False" />
                <ClientSettings
                    AllowKeyboardNavigation="False"
                    EnableRowHoverStyle="True"
                    EnablePostBackOnRowClick="False">
                    <KeyboardNavigationSettings
                        EnableKeyboardShortcuts="False" />
                    <Selecting CellSelectionMode="1" ></Selecting>
                    <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="showCashDetailWindowDblClick"></ClientEvents>
                </ClientSettings>
                <MasterTableView
                    TableLayout="Fixed" Height="14px" border-left-width="0px" Font-Names="Calibri" font-Size="9">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Account" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataField="Account" DataType="System.String" Display="True" 
                            ShowFilterIcon="false" UniqueName="Account" >
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding"  Width="95px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="CCY" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="LocalCurrency" UniqueName="LocalCurrency"> <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" Width="30px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="NAV" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="NavValue" UniqueName="NAV" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="GV Settled Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false"
                            DataField="GVSettledLocal" UniqueName="GVSettledLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="GV Trade Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false"
                            DataField="GVTradeLocal" UniqueName="GVTradeLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="GV Pending Trade (ex Div)" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="GVPendingTrade" UniqueName="GVPendingTrade" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FX Pending Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="FXPendingLocal" UniqueName="FXPendingLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Wires Pending Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="GVPendingWire" UniqueName="GVPendingWire" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="GV Settled as % NAV" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="GVSettledBasePctNav" UniqueName="GVSettledBasePctNav" DataFormatString="{0:##0.00#%;(##0.00#%);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="55px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="BK Settled Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="BankSettledLocal" UniqueName="BankSettledLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}"> 
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Local Settled Diff" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="LocalSettledDiff" UniqueName="LocalSettledDiff" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Comments" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Comments" UniqueName="Comments"> <HeaderStyle Width="90px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Make Trade?" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="MakeTrade" UniqueName="MakeTrade"> <HeaderStyle Width="90px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Trade Amount" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TradeAmount" UniqueName="TradeAmount" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="75px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Trade %" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.String" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TradePercent" UniqueName="TradePercent"  DataFormatString="{0:###,##0.00#%;(###,##0.00#)%;#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="C A C S" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="CACS" UniqueName="CACS"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="F X" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="FX" UniqueName="FX"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="I n c / E x p" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="IncExp" UniqueName="IncExp"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="T r a d e" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Trade" UniqueName="Trade"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="W i r e" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Wire" UniqueName="Wire"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="O t h e r" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Int32" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="Other" UniqueName="Other"> <HeaderStyle Width="18px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Txfr Amount" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TransferAmount" UniqueName="TransferAmount" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="80px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Settle Post" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="SettlePost" UniqueName="SettlePost" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Trade Post" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="TradePost" UniqueName="TradePost" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="GV Div Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" ShowFilterIcon="false" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" 
                            DataField="GVDivLocal" UniqueName="GVDivLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FX Forward Pending Local" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="FxFwdPendingLocal" UniqueName="FxFwdPendingLocal" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="95px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Misc Accruals" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="MiscAccruals" UniqueName="MiscAccruals" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Non-Trading Accruals" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="NonTradingAccruals" UniqueName="NonTradingAccruals" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Mgmt and Incentive Fees" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="noPadding" 
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                            CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" DataType="System.Double" Display="True" ShowFilterIcon="false" 
                            DataField="MgmtIncentiveFees" UniqueName="MgmtIncentiveFees" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,##0.00;(###,###,###,##0.00);#.##}">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="85px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:radgrid>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```